# Get n lines from file which are equal spaced

Tags: bash, sed

I have a big file with 1000 lines.I wanted to get 110 lines from it.
Lines should be evenly spread in Input file.

For example,I have read 4 lines from file with 10 lines

Input File

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

outFile:

```
1
4
7
10
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
sed -n '1~9p' < file
```

The `-n` option will stop `sed` from outputting anything. `'1~9p'`  tells `sed` to print from line 1 every 9 lines (the `p` at the end orders `sed` to print).

To get closer to 110 lines you have to print every 9th line (1000/110 ~ 9).

---

**Update:** This answer will print 112 lines, if you need exactly 110 lines, you can limit the output just using `head` like this:

```
sed -n '1~9p' < file | head -n 110
```

Comment: It's printing first 9 lines.

Comment: It was a typo (an extra `,`), fixed

Comment: int(1000 / 9) = 111, not 110.

Comment: There is no integer that divides 1000 into 110 (_int(1000 / 10) = 100, int(1000 / 9) = 111, int(1000 / 8) = 125_). The answer prints 112 lines in a file with 1000 lines (tested with `printf "%s\n" {1..1000} | sed -n '1~9p' | wc -l`), just 2 extra lines. The OP can pipe `head` if these 2 extra lines are a concern.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The OP is looking for a tool that will print N evenly-spaced lines from an input file, that's all. Not a solution where he has to figure out the spacing for himself and then keep track of how many lines is output and then run some other tool to remove any extra lines.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { next }
FNR==1 { mod = int((NR-1)/tgt) }
!( (FNR-1)%mod ) { print; cnt++ }
cnt == tgt { exit }

$ wc -l file1
1000 file1

$ awk -v tgt=110 -f tst.awk file1 file1 > file2

$ wc -l file2
110 file2

$ head -5 file2
1
10
19
28
37

$ tail -5 file2
946
955
964
973
982
```

Note that this will not produce the output you posted in your question given your posted input file because that would require an algorithm that doesn't always use the same interval between output lines. You could dynamically calculate `mod` and adjust it as you parse your input file if you like but the above may be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

With awk you can do:

```
 awk -v interval=3 '(NR-1)%interval==0' file
```

where interval is the difference in line count between consecutive lines that are printed. The value is essentially a division of the total lines in the file divided by the number of lines that are printed.

Answer (score 2):

I often like to use a combination of shell and awk for these sorts of things

```
#!/bin/bash

filename=$1
toprint=$2

awk -v tot=$(expr $(wc -l < $filename)) -v toprint=$toprint '
BEGIN{ interval=int((tot-1)/(toprint-1)) }

(NR-1)%interval==0 {
    print;
    nbr++
}

nbr==toprint{exit}

' $filename
```

Some examples:

```
$./spread.sh 1001lines 5
1
251
501
751
1001
$ ./spread.sh 1000lines 110 |head -n 3
1
10
19
$ ./spread.sh 1000lines 110 |tail -n 3
964
973
982
```